# Is there a wiki bot for deleting articles based on a regex?

Tags: delete, wiki, mediawiki

My problem is that I have added many (about 200) images with a wiki bot to our company's wiki, a MediaWiki.

Now I want to delete all the images I have uploaded. I gave them all a name with a specified prefix. I planned to use the prefix to delete them. The problem now is that MediaWiki doesn't provide a function for deleting multiple articles.

My idea was to use a wiki bot to do this task. But before I'm starting to write an, own I want to ask: Is there such a bot already? I'm looking for a wiki bot that could delete articles in MediaWiki based on a regex. Does anybody know such a tool?

Answer (score 0):

Start with an apprefix query from the [mediawiki query API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aAllpages). Then see the mediawiki delete API command.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? The way it is now, it's not very helpful.